# Can deleted history from Chrome be accessed?

Tags: google-chrome, history, browsing

I received a question from a co-worker recently about whether a manual delete of all browsing history, cookies, etc. from Google Chrome History can nevertheless be accessed by any software after the fact.  He came to me in confidence, afraid of what website browsing may be discovered by an advanced history search.  Any advice or knowledge on the topic?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If he's a **co-worker** and this was done at **work** then it's all on the server, so it doesn't matter what's on his machine.

Answer (score 1):

The history aswell as the cookies and browser cache are stored in a cache folder (%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default). These files are just normal files and if deleted then they are either in the bin or deleted from the hdd.

You could try some recovery tool to get the files back, but I do not think it would be easy.

Comment: Thank you. And how is that path (the C drive) accessed? Sorry for the amateurism over here.

Comment: I've updated the path above. If you copy the path, then you can press `Win + R`, paste the code in to the box and press `Enter`